# Get-AzureAutomationJob CreationTime Type

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

When I run this code in Azure Automation, the type of `CreationTime` is `String`. However when I run it in Powershell ISE, the type is `DateTimeOffset`.
Why is this?:

```
$job = Get-AzureAutomationJob -Id '6edcaf79-f924-480d-9242-8c113206d7cb' -AutomationAccountName nonprodruntimebuild
$type = $job.CreationTime.GetType().Name
Write-Output $type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug. The DateTimeOffset fields returned in Azure Automation cmdlets are instead strings in PowerShell Workflow. The workaround is to convert them back to DateTimes like so:

```
$datetimeoffset = Get-Date $job.CreationTime
```

Comment: But then you lose any time data smaller than a second, ie. milliseconds, since $job.CreationTime returns a string that only goes down to seconds.

Comment: You could wrap the cmdlet that outputs the job in an InlineScript. This would cause the cmdlet to be run in PowerShell, rather than PowerShell Workflow, therefore DateTimeOffset fields would not be converted to strings.